# How to Switch Columns in excel?

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a table with 4 columns and i need to Switch their order in this way.

[image]

How can i do this with one command? Because if I have a high number of columns I can't do this one by one.
Thank You.

Comment: Have you researched anything yourself? A simple formula will do this I think, and possibly some PowerQuery magic. VBA can also do this quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR : use offset() , row() & column()

Long version :

put `=OFFSET($A$1,ROW()-1,10-COLUMN())`  in G1 and drag.

the only thing you need to figure out is.. the value '10' in the formulae.. it adjusts depending on how many column you are shifting. ( :